# Making sense of Laravel and cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, laravel

This is the first time I'm working with both cookies and Laravel. I'm trying to store a simple value, `sectionID`, and retrieve it for the user so that they can continue working from their last visited section. If there is no saved value, I want to return 0.

Server side routes:

```
Route::get('cookieget', function() {
    return Cookie::get('sectionID', 0);
});

Route::post('cookieset', function() {
     Cookie::make('sectionID', Input::get('sectionID'), 60*24);
});
```

Client side is quite complex but these are the relevant parts:

UserController.js

```
function UserController(userID) {
    var outer = this;

    ...

    this.setCookie = function(maxUserSectionID) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "cookieset",
            data: {
                sectionID: maxUserSectionID
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Set max sectionID cookie to " + maxUserSectionID);
            }
        });
    }

    this.getSectionIDFromCookie = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "cookieget",
            async: false,
            success: sectionController.handleNewSection
        });


    }
}
```

SectionController.js

```
function SectionController(editor, lessonNr)
{

    // setup initial data
    // the 0-based index of the current section
    this.currentSection = null;
    // the furthest the user has reached in this lesson
    this.maxSection = 0;
...

    // methods

    this.nextSection = function() {

        if (outer.currentSection > outer.maxSection) {
            outer.maxSection = outer.currentSection;
            userController.setCookie(outer.lessonJSON['sections'][outer.maxSection]['sectionID']);
        }

    ...
    };

    ...

    this.checkCookie = function() {
        userController.getSectionIDFromCookie();
    }

    this.handleNewSection = function(newSectionID) {
        alert(newSectionID);
        outer.currentSection = parseInt(newSectionID);
...
    }

    // called from outside as "constructor"
    this.setup = function() {
        ...
    outer.checkCookie();
    }

}
```

First of all, my main problem is that the cookie always returns 0, even though I'm sure that `setCookie` is called successfully.

Second, I'm wondering if there's more elegant ways of doing it? I assume now it puts a lot of load on the server if isers are moving through sections too quickly.

Comment: Tried `var_dump(Input::get('sectionID'))` on the `cookieset` route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must return a response with cookie to set your cookie properly:

```
Route::post('cookieset', function() {
    $response = Response::make('Hello World');

    return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('sectionID', Input::get('sectionID'), 60*24););
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. What about the structure of the client, is this a good way to work with cookies in general?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it, but I'm no javascript specialist.

Comment: I will mark this question as answered. However, I found that cookies are not what I was looking for.